# left of '.push_back' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Why can't I use the vector? Is it not initialized? can't I access the member data in a static function?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/thread.hpp> 
#include<vector>
#include<boost/asio.hpp> 
#include <ctime>
#include <string>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}

class maintain_overlay{

public:
    maintain_overlay():thread_(&maintain_overlay::member_list_server)
    {
        thread_.join();
    }
    static void member_list_server(){
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

        for (;;)
        {
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);

            member_list.push_back(socket.remote_endpoint());

            std::string message = make_daytime_string();

            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message),
                boost::asio::transfer_all(), ignored_error);


        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<tcp::endpoint> member_list;
    boost::thread thread_;

};
```

-----edit---

my server wants to maintain a list of all the incoming tcp conections?
What is the best way to do this?
Should I declare member_list static?
When I do that I get an error `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `member_list_server()` function is static, and you are trying to access a data member.

That would only be possible if your member function were not static, so that it would receive an implicit `this` pointer on which to access the `member_list` data member.

You should make your function non-static and use `boost::bind()` when constructing your `thread` object:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

maintain_overlay()
    :
    thread_(boost::bind(&maintain_overlay::member_list_server, this))
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    thread_.join();
}

void member_list_server() {
// ...
}
```

Alternatively, if that is appropriate for the semantics of your class, you may make `member_list` a static data member. In that case, do not forget to provide a *definition* for it at namespace scope:

```
class maintain_overlay
{
    // ...
private:
    static std::vector<tcp::endpoint> member_list; // DECLARATION
//  ^^^^^^
};

std::vector<tcp::endpoint> maintain_overlay::member_list; // DEFINITION
```

Comment: When i try to make it static I get linking error, what do u mean by  In that case, do not forget to provide a definition for it at namespace scope? could u plz explain in detial

Comment: thanks...that fixed it, but I still dont get why defining outside without the static keyword works?

Comment: @user494461: What do you mean? Also, if that solves your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I mean why do static members need definition outside class so that we can assign memory to it? non static members get initliased automatically right?

Comment: @user494461: Well, that's a very different question and I would suggest asking on SO (or looking for existing Q&As). In short, that's because static members are global for all the instances of that class, so a global definition for them must be present (with rare exceptions) - the compiler needs to know the address of that object.

Answer (score 0):

`member_list` is not a `static` variable and is being accessed in the `static` member function `member_list_server()`. `member_list` can only be accessed via an instance of `maintain_overlay`.

Example fix using [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html) (which Andy posted first, as I had to compile and be certain before posting):

```
maintain_overlay() :
    thread_(boost::bind(&maintain_overlay::member_list_server, this))

void member_list_server(){
```